# R Text Mining using tm pacakge with variables from csv

Tags: r, ggplot2, text-mining, tm, corpus

I am completing a project in which I using R to text mine and compare this to other variables. I am relatively new to programming so any help would be appreciated.

I have a csv file with over 100 variables and one of the variables is a comment section filled with text. I have managed to clean the file and treat the the column as a corpus and remove english stop words, remove punctuation etc. Here is the code for this, with the first quarter data file read in:

```
com <- read.csv("dataQ1", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

Then remove NA and blank spaces

```
comna <- com[!(is.na(com$Comment) | com$Comment==""), ]
```

Create a corpus to clean further, this done by using the `tm package` and helps remove punctation, numbers and english stopwords (words like 'and' or 'the') amongst other things as shown in this code.

```
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(comna$Comment)) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower, mc.cores=1) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, mc.cores=1, removePunctuation) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers, mc.cores=1) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"), mc.cores=1) 
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
```

Now I would like to explore the data by comparing this to another variable in csv file like 'Overall Satisfaction.' So if I extract certain words like 'abroad,' and 'charges,' and then plot this in ggplot as follows by using the following code:

```
wordExtr <- subset(comna, grepl("abroad|charges", Comment))

os <- ggplot(wordExtr, aes(factor(wordExtr$Overall.Satisfaction))) 
c + geom_bar()
```

Giving the following ggplot:[image]

**However** this plot is comparing the variable on when blank spaces and NAs have been removed I would like to compare the variable to corpus object I created which removed punctuation, capital letters, stopwords etc. So my two questions are as follows.

**1. How do I select the column that I have created a corpus object and compare this to the 'overall satifaction,' varaible?** i.e not the column that has just the NAs and blank spaces removed as shown above.

**2. As stated I have read in quarter 1, can I read in quarter 2 and plot on the same ggplot the results of quater 2?** So for example I would like a graph that measures the 'overall satisfaction,' over 4 quarters.

Any help in how I can code this would really help, and if there is anything that is unclear, please ask with a follow up question. Thanks

Comment: You seem to missing a required package. A reproducible example would also help.

Comment: A package for what? Essentially I have cleaned the csv file in two stages the first being removing NAs and blanks, secondly creating corpus to further clean it. I can plot it when I have cleaned the csv in the first stage as the other variables can still be selected. But I struggle to plot it after the second stage. Is there a way of selecting the required variable after the second stage?

Comment: `tm_map` is not a base R command, and I don't know what a `Corpus` object is. They are probably in a package, and you should add that to the question, possibly with a tag.

Comment: I understand now, I used the tm pacakge to create a corpus (A corpus is body of work made up of a collection of documents so our case each comment is treated as a document). When you create a corpus you can then clean it. This is done by selecting the required column, but I struggle to match the comments from the corpus to another variable, which is my second stage of cleaning. But I hope the change in the question may help.